# Consecutive visa applications

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas

I applied for a tourist visa to visit my wife in Germany about a month ago.Recently I got a contract letter from German company,hence I need to apply a national visa to travel and work there.I have an Indian nationality and currently residing in Kualalumpur Malaysia for last 18 months with a valid Malaysian employment pass till October 22nd 2019.My wife is also an Indian and staying at Germany for last 9 months for her MBA program.Will I need to submit any additional documents for consecutive visa applications (i.e. tourist visa and national visa) to Germany?I am bit worried about this.Kindly let me know.

Comment: The conditions for the application for a work visa is based on nationality (i. e. if you **must** apply in your home country or not). Give a reference to the first application as well as citizenship and residence status of your wife. Based on this information, the process **could be** started now and you could be allowed to continue it during your visit.

Comment: Thank you @MarkJohnson.As my wife is a student in Germany I do have her the residence permit copy,student id card copy,passport copy and  marriage certificate with me which I can provide to embassy if they ask me during my national visa process.

Comment: Please adapt your question with the nationality and residence status so that proper answer can be made.

Comment: I have an Indian nationality and currently residing in Kualalumpur Malaysia for last 18 months with a valid Malaysian employment pass till October 22nd 2019.My wife is also an Indian and staying at Germany for last 9 months.

Answer (score 1):

As an Indian citizen you are required to make the application for a work visa at a consulate responsible for the area of your main residence (which in this case is not your home country).

The application will be decided (in most cases) by the local Foreigners Office in Germany and can take up to 3 months.

It would be **wise** to inform the Cousulate of the other, independent, visitor visa application.

It may even simplify the second application, since much of the need information is already available.